# Uniqueness and existence of an infinite probability distribution extending finite probability distributions

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, limits-colimits

Let $I$ be a (possibly infinite) set. To each finite subset $J$ of $I$, we associate a joint probability distribution $X_J$ whose sample space is $\mathbb R^J$ (i.e. the outcomes are $|J|$-tuples). Moreover, if $J' \subseteq J \subseteq I$, then $X_{J'}$ and $X_J$ are compatible in the sense that if $F \sim X_{J}$, then $F {\restriction_{J'}} \sim X_{J'}$. I have two question:

1. Is there a probability distribution $X_I$ over $\mathbb R^I$ such that $F \sim X_I$ implies $F {\restriction_{J}} \sim X_{J}$?
2. Is this $X_I$ unique?

Essentially, we are trying to describe the probability distribution of $|I|$ random variables in terms of the distributions on finite sets of those variables.

This appears to be some sort of [inverse limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_limit), or maybe has something to do with Sheafs, but I do not really know the details in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kolmogorov's Extension Theorem deals with the existence of the product measure on $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$, which is built from a sequence of consistent, finite-dimensional measures. See Theorem 2.1.21 in the former reference or Theorem 9.1 in the latter.

https://services.math.duke.edu/~rtd/PTE/PTE5_011119.pdf
http://bass.math.uconn.edu/math5160f14/post9.pdf

Does this answer your question?

Comment: Yes, it seems like the Kolmogorov Extension theorem is exactly what I wanted, thank you!